# Centering layers in OpenLayers v4 after layer loading

Tags: openlayers, vector-layer

I have a group of layers in OpenLayers, and I can see each one on the map, when I click on the checkbox to show it.

```
var group_layers = new ol.layer.Group({
    title: 'My Group',
    fold: 'close',
    layers: [
        layer1,
        layer2,
        layer3,
    ]
});

map.addLayer(group_layers)
```

And I need to center the layer on the map after it's loaded.
But when I run the "once" function in source, I notice that it loads the data from source twice. What did I do wrong?

```
var layer1 = new ol.layer.Vector({
    title: 'Layer 1',
    visible: false,
    zIndex: abrangencia,
    style: style_cadastro_lote,
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        url: function(extent) {
            return urlGeoserver +'wfs?service=WFS&' +
              'version='+versionGeoserver+'&request=GetFeature&typename=geo:LAYER1&' +
              'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326&' +
              'all=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:4326';  
                
        },
        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
    })
}); 
 
layer1.getSource().once('change', function() {
    map.getView().fit(layer1.getSource().getExtent(), map.getSize());
    map.getView().setZoom(19)
});

layer2.getSource().once('change', function() {
    map.getView().fit(layer2.getSource().getExtent(), map.getSize());
    map.getView().setZoom(19)
});

layer3.getSource().once('change', function() {
    map.getView().fit(layer3.getSource().getExtent(), map.getSize());
    map.getView().setZoom(19)
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bbox strategy is not approriate - if you need the extent of all the features in the source you must load them all:

```
var layer1 = new ol.layer.Vector({
    title: 'Layer 1',
    visible: false,
    zIndex: abrangencia,
    style: style_cadastro_lote,
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        url: urlGeoserver +'wfs?service=WFS&' +
              'version='+versionGeoserver+'&request=GetFeature&typename=geo:LAYER1&' +
              'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326&', 
        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.all
    })
});
```

If you have multiple layers you would presumable want to combine the extents, otherwise you would center on whichever happened to take longer to load.  As each layer loads, regardless of the timing, you can extend the extent:

```
var combinedExtent = ol.extent.createEmpty();

layer1.getSource().once('change', function() {
    ol.extent.extend(combinedExtent, layer1.getSource().getExtent())
    map.getView().fit(combinedExtent, map.getSize());
});

layer2.getSource().once('change', function() {
    ol.extent.extend(combinedExtent, layer2.getSource().getExtent())
    map.getView().fit(combinedExtent, map.getSize());
});

layer3.getSource().once('change', function() {
    ol.extent.extend(combinedExtent, layer3.getSource().getExtent())
    map.getView().fit(combinedExtent, map.getSize());
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Mike, my mistake was `ol.loadingstrategy.bbox` itself, which was duplicating the layers. It worked out.